# Display fragments in main view based on selection in sidebar menu in react-native.

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to change the content view based on the selection of sidebar menu option.
The header and sidebar menu should not change.

```
var Something = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var menu = <SideBarMenu/>;

    return (
        <SideMenu menu={menu}>
          <Header />
          <ContentView/>
        </SideMenu>
      );
  }
});
```

I'm confused about how to change the content view based on some property changed in sidebar menu component because these two are different component sidebarmenu and contentview.

[image: Sample App]

Answer (score 1):

The is what Flux can help. In your SideBarMenu, create an action to change data in your store, then in you ContentView listen to the same store change event, then update its state. There are lots of Flux implementations, most populars are [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) from facebook and [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) .